Does Judaism care if jesus performed the miracles as reported in the christian testament?
Devarim 13 teaches about a navi sheker that can predict the future accurately and/or perform miracles (real ones—see Rashbam), and yet, as he contravenes the Torah, that we ourselves heard, we're to disregard him, and even have him eliminated. As for the miracles, HaShem is testing our faith, see there.
That being said, does Judaism care if the christian miracles occurred or is it agnostic to them as jc was no more than a navi sheker (ditto for other religions and their miracle claims)?

I have a feeling this has been raised before here on Mi Yodeya. Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan wrote that he was even okay with the possibility that he did in fact perform miracles, but was intended as a prophet to a non-Jewish audience only. Of course the really nasty things you'll find in some midrashim reflect the "divorce period" between the two faiths, so ... they are nasty.

@Shalom I'd be curious to see that thought from RAK if you're able to track it down

Doubtful he was a real person

Based on the fact that the Talmud provides numerous examples of miracles performed by the Talmudic sages, I see no reason to deny that from other [Kosher] Jews (given a furious argument between Jesus' brother James/Jacob and Paul regarding the importance of the observance of Biblical Mitzvos in the process of salvation, it appears that Jesus was a Kosher, albeit Messianic, Jew. His portrayal was greatly distorted in the late gospels.).

@Dude R' Tovia Singer, while not a historian himself, is convinced that Jesus was a real person. Part of that is because the Christian Bible is compelled to shoehorn the "Messiah from Bethlehem" nonsense into a guy who's actually from Nazareth, when Nazareth is a one-horse backwater town that no one ever heard of.

The general consensus among historians, @Dude, is that he was a real person, though much of his biography as told in the Gospels is heavily fictionalised.

@TRiG many assume so but there aren't any primary sources which demonstrate this. Even places in the talmud assumed to refer to him can't be referring to the same person as time frames don't match.

I don't think Judaism cares. Let's give Joshua son of Joseph (aka Jesus) the benefit of the doubt and say he did perform miracles of healing. Okay great, so he's a prophet. We've got dozens of those, men and women, Israelite and Gentile. The Messiah is supposed to at some point usher in a time of great peace, where nations will beat their swords into plowshares and spears into pruning hooks  (Isaiah 2:2-4). Until that happens it doesn't matter how many miracles a single prophet performs. They could have a regular act at The Magic Castle with a hundred miracles a night, doesn't make them the Messiah.

The discussion in the Talmud does not deal with the actual Jesus and his actual acts, as has been established even by christian scholars like Johann Maier. The Talmud, written many years after the supposed events, does not deny that the miracles described by Christians could take place. However, the Talmud associates such miracles with deception, sorcery, and idolatry, which are forbidden in Judaism (Bavli Sanhedrin 107b and Sotah 47a). For example, Bavli Shabbos 104b R. Eliezer asks: But did not ben Stada bring forth witchcraft from Egypt by means of scratches/tatoos (biseritah) upon his flesh? (a similar point in Yerushalmi Shabbos 12:4/3).
The message is, paraphrasing Peter Schaefer's words in "Jesus in Talmud" when he discussed cases of healing: the fact, that Heaven accepted some acts described by followers of Jesus, did not mean that it approved of them, because they were based on unauthorized and misused power. The fact, that something miraculous but not approved can happen, we learn in the Torah in parashas Chukas, when Moshe strikes the rock twice and water flows; however, the action is not approved by Hashem. The Talmud uses the subject to teach importance not to resort to such behavior. Judaism is a religion based on law and miracles are not viewed as a reason to abandon the law as the words about Navi Sheker tell us.

Highly related: Why don’t Jews think Jesus is the messiah?
Being the Mashiach has very little, if anything at all, to do with what miracles a person can perform. Assuming the man named Jesus of Nazareth performed all of those miracles as reported in the Christian Bible, it would have very little impact on how Judaism sees him. He still did not gather the exiles, bring world peace, and re-establish the Davidic kingdom, as promised in the prophecies in the Tanakh.
So to answer your question: not in the slightest.

Nah.
Jesus lived in the time of תנאים. Lots of תנאים and אמוראים were practitioners of practical Kabbalah. Recorded in various parts of the Talmud (and some concurrent texts) are stories of Rabbis performing feats beyond the laws of nature in something similar to small-scale open miracles.
Jesus may have been one such Rabbi, and used his knowledge for bad reasons, attaining a following by performing impossible feats, and then leading them in a form of radicalism that eventually turned into Christianity.
Another possibility is that Jesus became a sorcerer, maybe because he was mad that nobody accepted him because he was a literal bastard. He may have done the same thing as the above paragraph, but using sorcery instead of practical Kabbalah.
Of course, he may not have performed any unnatural feats, and the stories of “miracles” recorded in Christian scriptures are just another part of their lies.
Either way, it doesn’t matter. Jesus was a radicalist and Christianity is really stupid. Don’t forget that.


Jesus was a talmid of Yehoshua ben Perachia. I.e. a tanna. Mishna was composed in 200 CE. 2. What is practical kabbala? In those days they only had merkavah mysticism. 3. There were practices of magic.


@YDJ 1. Good point. Will fix after this. 2. I don’t mean the medieval practical Kabbalah. I’m referring to the fact that many of the early Rabbanim ubderstood secrets of the Torah, and knew how to manipulate creation in order to perform things outside of the natural order. 3. Added already.

I read the comment again. Such an approach maybe a slippery slope. What prompted J* to use knowledge for stupid reasons if he learned to become a rabbi and have many students? Or become a sourcerer? Personally I subscribe to a theory of Roman provenance, that Christianity was a Roman effort to modify Judaism from outside to serve as an imperial religion. Romans created such religions in every country that they conquered.

@YDJ The leaders of progressive religions which label themselves as forms of Judaism, usually know a decent amount of תנ״ך and Talmud, yet they ignore all of it. Knowledge does not necessarily correlate to non-radicalism. And I meant that he might have attained a following, only BECAUSE of his impossible feats.

Those religions do not have the following that Christianity gained, nor they supplant the religions for representatives of other nations and religions. These progressive religions only exist as a unique Jewish phenomenon.

@YDJ Yes. I used them as examples of the idea that knowledge may not always lead to goodness or wisdom.

I want to upvote your answer but I can't because of your calling the students of Jesus crazy and calling Christianity stupid.

@Aaron They turned the Jesus-movement messianic. Of course they were crazy. And Christianity claims that a man who went against every qualification of the משיח, and who died before achieving anything, was actually the messiah, and also a god. Like, come on.

@QwertyCTRL. I think most of the complaints you have don't have to do with his students. As far as I can tell his students remained observantly Jewish and wanted to remain so. Early Hebrew copies of Matthew were reported to represent Jesus as the son of Joseph. It seems to me that Paul, who NEVER MET JESUS, and his gentile followers were the ones who changed everything around.

Thank you, @Aaron. I wasn’t aware of that nuance.

Just  because someone lived in the times of the  Tanaim, or even studied with them, that doesn't make them a Tana. Automatic -1

Okay, @N.T. I changed it to “lived with the תנאים.” Better?

@QwertyCTRL. I'm still not a fan of you calling Christianity stupid. I think they have a lot of incompatible beliefs, but I know quite a few Christians who have a logical faith and are knowledgeable. But other than that your answer is great. I think it might be more clarifying to talk about the chariots and the types of kabbalah discussed at this time. Take my +1

@Aaron, I didn’t claim that Christians were stupid. There are many reasonable, intelligent Christians, just as there are many intelligent people of other religions. But the religion itself is undoubtably stupid. It doesn’t make sense in the context of Judaism or in the context of morality.
